# Paperclip attachment size validation fails, but size is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, multipart, paperclip-validation

My model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  LOGO_TYPES = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
  VALID_LOGO_MESSAGE = 'Please attach a valid picture file containing your organization logo.  Valid formats are JPG, PNG, and GIF'

  has_attached_file :logo, :content_type => LOGO_TYPES,
  :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/uploads/articlelogos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :url => "/assets/uploads/articlelogos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => LOGO_TYPES, :message => VALID_LOGO_MESSAGE
  validates_attachment_size :logo, :less_than => 1.megabytes
end
```

When I try to upload a valid, 6k .gif logo using Paperclip, I get:

```
Logo_file_size file size must be between 0 and 1024 bytes
```

Logs as request hits :

```
Started PUT "/articles/74" for x.x.x.x at 2012-01-15 17:44:20 -0600
  Processing by ArticlesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uI+OXmV3B/crOrUopbBxpRs242PzMVJY1uM/QBnHdlE=", "article"=>{"logo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000081d70b0 @original_filename="test_logo.gif", @content_type="image/gif", 
  @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"article[logo]\"; filename=\"test_logo.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n", 
  @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120115-30606-1wwkr21>>}, "commit"=>"Upload Now", "id"=>"74"}
```

And I added some debugging to show the tempfile

```
params[:article][:logo].inspect: #<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120115-30606-1wwkr21>>
params[:article][:logo].size: 6531
```

So it is clearly being stored on the server, but Paperclip is failing to check the size properlly.

This works on my local Mac in development mode, but fails on production under Ubuntu.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

**Update - removing size validation enables the file to be uploaded and stored as usual**

Comment: just wondering what happens if you change `:less_than => 1.megabytes` to `:less_than => 1.megabyte`

Comment: Also your class doesn't appear to be extending ActiveRecord or any other ORM, and you don't declare any attr_accessors, perhaps this is causing issues

Comment: Your correct, the code has ActiveRecord::Base, forgot to include in my post, corrected now.

Comment: Changing to 1.megabyte had no-effect, thanks for suggestion though

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be, but try using `:less_than => 1048576` instead of the `megabytes` helper. It appears that it's checking for under one kilobyte.